# Trouble with injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have a problem where injection fails on first try but not on second.  My app is laid out like this (this is a Java EE application using Maven in Eclipse):

```
@Stateful
@Named("myBean")
@SessionScoped

public class MyBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private User user;
...

@PostConstruct
public String init() {
.. do some general tasks, no issues here.
}

public String initApplication() { // this gets called on page load
   String userId = user.getId(); 
...
}

....  in another class...

@Produces
@SessionScoped
@Named("user")
public User produceUser() {
  // code to create user is here
}
```

Symptom: I start the browser, clear the cache, start the application. I get a null on `user` the `@Produces` method is never called. I call the same URL again to start the application, and then it works.

Comment: The error I get is User$Proxy$_$$WeldClientProxy.getId line:not available (local variables unavailable).  But if I just call the application again, then injection happens and I can access User variables.

Answer (score 2):

Named injection can be a little unstable on some EE servers when used in combination with `@Produces`. Not only this, but it actually creates a completely separate instance with ambiguity. So if you have a User bean defined in session scope somewhere else they are considered two different sources of injection. Maybe that's what's happening and it's picking up the second one when you reload?

What happens if you move away from the `@Produces` (remove `produceUser()`) and instead do;

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {
    @PostConstruct
    private init() {
        /* Do what you did in the producer method here */
    }
}
```

That should really work - otherwise something is seriously wrong.

Comment: The problem there is that the whole User instantiation process is tied to our CAS login session.  It would be difficult to port that code to my bean.  What I don't understand is that I use this exact same setup in multiple projects, same setup (Java/Hibernate/Maven/Primefaces), and this is the first time I've encountered any issues.It is frustrating because it's hard to trace what is going on.

Comment: @TomT What EE server are you running?

Comment: Glassfish v2, for now.

Comment: Here is a little more detail on what is happening and when.  I am testing locally, so I start my Glassfish server, start my browser.  I log in.  Injection fails.  If I call application again, it works.  If I clear cache and log in again, it works.  If I stop the Glassfish server, close the browser, and start over, it doesn't work.   Note that my bean is @ApplicationScoped, and the methods in my producer bean are either session or application-scoped, depending on the need.

Comment: @TomT Yes I got that. My guess - you are hitting a bug in your CDI/weld implementation. GlassFish v2 is extremely old and the "current" EE version back then was EE5 if I recall correctly. Even if you add a newer version of Weld as a dependency, you can't fully trust it's behavior - because the application server itself may (and probably will) have problems to cope with the implementation. Please move up to something more recent and see if that fixes your issue. Preferably go with something recent so you get a fairly new Weld implementation tested with that version of the application server.

Comment: We are actually planning to migrate this application to Payara, so hopefully this problem will disappear.  Thanks.

Comment: @TomT Let us know how it goes - if it persists it might be interesting to dig deeper.

Comment: I discovered something interesting: if I create a @PostConstruct method with a try/catch, where both the try and the catch call user.getId(), it works:  the first call throws the exception, and then the injection happens in the exception block.  So I'm calling it twice to get it to work.

Comment: @TomT The whole point of a `@PostConstruct` is to guarantee that all injection points are available. So something is else is going on. Weld would not be invoked because of a try/catch.

Comment: I was able to fix this, but not sure why.  An exception was being thrown in a CDIExtension class because of a null WebApplication variable.  Someone suggested this fix: in my Resources class, I commented out  `@Resource WebServiceContext context` and `@Context HttpServletRequest request` .  One of these removals fixed the problem, and now injection works.

Comment: @TomT Sorry - missed your comment. That is most definitely a bug - so I as I suspected the problem probably lies with the old weld implementation of the application server. It's interesting that particular solution solves it ;). I have to say though - I have a vague memory of `@Context HttpServletRequest` causing problems in some instances a long time ago with older implementations.